# Cakephp data validation "notEmpty" "required"

Tags: php, mysql, validation, cakephp

I'm a newbie to cake, done the blog tutorial and now I'm trying something simple to start.
But I got something I can't understand.
On model PersonalInformation I got the data validation for the table fields:

This is my model with the $validate array:

```
class PersonalInformation extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 * @var $validate
 */
public $validate = array(
    "first_name" => array(
        "name"      => array(
            "rule"      => "validName",
            "message"   => 'Only alpha characters and "." (dots)',
        ),
    ),
    "last_name"  => array(
        "name"      => array(
            "rule"      => "validName",
            "message"   => 'Only alpha characters and "." (dots)',
        ),
    ),
    "birth_date" => array(
        "date"      => array(
            "rule"      => "date",
            "message"   => "Enter a valid date",
        ),
    ),
    "nickname"  => array(
        "alphanumeric"  => array(
            "rule"      => "alphaNumeric",
            "message"   => "Only alpha-numeric characters",
        ),
    ),
    "gender"     => array(
        "notEmpty"  => array(
            "rule"          => "notEmpty",
            "message"       => "Can't be empty",
        ),
    ),
);

} // end class
```

And this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_informations`
(
`id` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` VARCHAR(45),
`last_name` VARCHAR(45),
`birth_date` DATE,
`nickname` VARCHAR(45),
`is_company` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
`picture_url` VARCHAR(255),
`gender` ENUM('m','f') NOT NULL,
`notes` TEXT,
`created` DATETIME,
`modified` DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8;

CREATE INDEX `id_idx` ON personal_informations(id);
```

And here is the view:

```
<!-- /PersonalInformations/add -->

<div class="">
<h2>Create a personal information</h2>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create();

    echo $this->Form->input( "PersonalInformation.first_name" );
    echo $this->Form->input( "PersonalInformation.last_name" );
    echo $this->Form->input( 
        "PersonalInformation.birth_date", 
        array( 
            "separator" => " - ", 
            "minYear" => date('Y') - 90,
            "maxYear" => date('Y')
    )
    );
    echo $this->Form->input( "PersonalInformation.nickname" );
    echo $this->Form->input( "PersonalInformation.is_company", array( "type" =>     "checkbox" ));
    echo $this->Form->input( "PersonalInformation.piture_url", array( "type" => "file"     ));
    echo $this->Form->radio( "PersonalInformation.gender", array( "m" => __("Male"), "f"     => __("Female")), array( "hiddenField" => false ));
    echo $this->Form->textarea( "PersonalInformation.notes" );

    echo $this->Form->end( "Done" );
    ?>
</div>
```

So the problem is that for some reason the "nickname" is kind of required, I mean, when I click on submit button with the "nickname" empty it shows "Only alpha-numeric characters".
And for the "gender" it doesn't show anything when none is selected.

If there is anything else that I need to post, just let me know.

Comment: The "allowEmpty" worked.
I had tried that before, the problem is that it was out of the nickname array and I've just noticed that on ADmad post
THanks all
(unfortanly i can't vote up)

Answer (score 1):

For your nickname

```
'nickname' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Nick name is required.'
            )
        )
```

For Gender:

In the view

```
echo $this->Form->input('PersonalInformation.gender',array(
          'type'=>'select','empty' => '---- Select----',
          'class'=>'select',
          'options'=>$option_array
          ))
```

In Model Validate array:

```
'gender' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Can\'t be empty.'
            )
        )
```

Comment: About gender i will test asap,
but about the nickname, i dont want it to be required, but for some reason it looks like it is when i click on submit, since it doesnt let me submit without filling the input.

Comment: What functionality you exactly need about nickname.

Comment: Be warned that, according to the documentation, "notEmpty" is deprecated as of version 2.7. The function that replaces it is "notBlank".

There is no explanation as to what was wrong with the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'allowEmpty' => true` for the rule for nickname.

```
 "nickname"  => array(
        "alphanumeric"  => array(
            "allowEmpty"=> true,
            "rule"      => "alphaNumeric",
            "message"   => "Only alpha-numeric characters",
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

For the nickname, have you tried to use `required => false` ?
You can read more about it [in the documentation.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required)

```
"nickname"  => array(
    "alphanumeric"  => array(
        "rule"      => "alphaNumeric",
        "required" => false,
        "message"   => "Only alpha-numeric characters",
    ),
),
```

Comment: Actually, "required" is not what he wants. From the docs you linked to: "The difference between required and allowEmpty can be confusing. 'required' => true means that you cannot save the model without the key for this field being present in $this->data (the check is performed with isset); whereas, 'allowEmpty' => false makes sure that the current field value is nonempty, as described above."